# Find items that are not tagged with the following tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to find all items with the provided tags and it works just fine:

```
select items.* 
from items 
inner join item_tag on items.id = item_tag.item_id 
where items.deleted_at is null and published = 1 
      and brand_id = 1 
      and item_tag.tag_id in (1,2,3) 
group by items.id 
having COUNT(DISTINCT item_tag.tag_id) = 3 order by id desc
```

I'm trying to make a query that returns all items that are not tagged by the provided tags and it doesn't work as expected.

```
select items.* 
from items 
inner join item_tag on items.id = item_tag.item_id 
where items.deleted_at is null and published = 1 
      and brand_id = 1 
      and item_tag.tag_id not in (4,5,6) 
group by items.id 
having COUNT(DISTINCT item_tag.tag_id) = 0 order by id desc
```

The query should also work with a combination of "in" and "not in" tags. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: it seems that the having clause might be causing issues, especially in the second query as having count(distinct tag_id)=0 would only be true if there are no tag_ids returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with the `having` clause will not work to exclude items with certain tags, so you'll need to approach that differently. In fact, without the `having` clause the second query would return better results.

Still you would not be able to combine `in` and `not in` conditions like that. For that case I suggest a query like this:

```
select      items.* 
from        items
inner join  (
                select   item_id, count(distinct tag_id) as matches
                from     item_tag
                where    tag_id in (1,2,3)
                group by item_id
            ) as tags_in
        on  tags_in.item_id = items.id
left join  (
                select   item_id
                from     item_tag
                where    tag_id in (4,5,6)
                group by item_id
            ) as tags_out
        on  tags_out.item_id = items.id
where       items.deleted_at is null
        and items.published = 1 
        and items.brand_id = 1 
        and tags_in.matches = 3
        and tags_out.id is null
```

So the first join gets the items with the count of tags that should be present, and the second join gets the items that have forbidden tags. Then the `where` clause performs the final test on both.